# Is the word "aliment" synonymous with "ailment"?

Tags: meaning

If someone [Googles the word 'aliment](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&biw=1242&bih=576&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=nws&ei=vMuwWvPWHYGEvQSyrJ6ACg&q=aliment%20&oq=aliment%20&gs_l=psy-ab.3...187330.189839.0.193406.66.14.0.0.0.0.232.1627.0j10j1.11.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..64.0.0....0.vIeTYf5gXDw)', he can see that by the word *aliment* they meant *ailment*.

[Merrium-Webster dictionary says](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aliment) that *aliment* = {*food*, *nutriment*, *sustenance*}.

Is this a mistake or is this a modern use of the word?

If this is a mistake, how is it possible that there are so many mistakes?

Comment: You're conflating examples where the word 'aliment' is actually intended with examples where it is an error and 'ailment' is intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they have different origins and different meanings:

***Aliment:***

> food, nutriment," late 15c., from Latin alimentum "nourishment," in plural, "food, provisions," from alere "to suckle, nourish," from PIE root [*al- (2)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*al-?ref=etymonline_crossreference) "to grow, nourish."

***Ailment:***

> "sickness, disease, indisposition," 1706, from [ail](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ail?ref=etymonline_crossreference) + -ment.

(Etymonline)

As the Grammarist suggests, the two terms are sometime confused, probably because of their similar spelling.

> ***[Ailment and aliment](http://grammarist.com/usage/ailment-vs-aliment/) are two words that may be confused***. We will examine the definitions of the words ailment and aliment, where they came from and some examples of their use in sentences.
>
> ***An ailment is an illness or sickness, though one that is probably but not always of minor importance***. Ailment is the noun form of the verb ail, meaning to afflict someone with a minor illness. Related words are ails, ailed, ailing. The word ailment is derived from the Old English word eglan, meaning to afflict, and the suffix -ment, used to transform verbs into nouns.
>
> ***Aliment is nourishment, food or comestibles***. The adjective form is alimental. The word aliment is derived from the Latin word alere, which means to nourish.
> ***Aliment is a somewhat archaic term***, and is usually found in classic literature or situations in which someone is deliberately attempting to sound old fashioned.

Answer (score 1):

Both 'aliment' and 'ailment' are real words and not connected with each other. 'Alimentary canal' (the stomach and intestines) is a more commonly-used expression than 'aliment' on its own. The derivation is the Latin 'alimentum' meaning nourishment.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a mix-up ailment is a sickness/infirmity. Aliment is more obscure or archaic, that means sustenance/food/nutrition.

> aliment
>
> 1. something that nourishes or sustains the body or mind
> 2. obsolete to support or sustain
>
> [C15: from Latin alimentum food, from alere to
>   nourish]
>
> Collins English Dictionary

Also the adjectival form:

> alimentary
>
> 1 : of or relating to nourishment or nutrition
>
> 2 :
>   furnishing sustenance or maintenance
>
> Merriam-Webster Dictionary

You can see the word alimentary used very commonly in anatomy, as in the alimentary canal.

[image]

The word in other Romance languages is just the ordinary word for feed in many cases. In French alimentation is feeding, in Spanish alimentar (to feed). And as we know, although our English is a Germanic language but its vocabulary is overwhelmingly Latin/Romance based.